# How do I sign my android app bundle with my upload key (without the keystore) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

So, I've gone through the whole process of uploading a signed app to the playstore, released it and opted in to the managed play store signing as recommended here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll

As part of this process, I generated a keystore file and upload key (both of which I have).

At the end of the above link, the article states:

> When you release your app after opting into App signing by Google
>   Play, Google Play generates and manages your app’s signing key for
>   you. Simply sign subsequent updates to your app using your app’s
>   upload key before uploading it to Google Play.
>   to me this means that I will **only** need the upload key and not the keystore file for future releases.

However, when I go back in to Android Studio to build the app bundle again (so I can publish another release), I select Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK and am then presented a modal like so:

[image]

The question is, how do I generate a new signed app bundle using **only** the upload key and not the keystore file?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253699/how-do-i-use-upload-cert-der-from-play-store-in-android-studio

Comment: @TWL In fact, that post does NOT answer my question (it answers almost everything else besides). I know how to get a upload key (I have it). My question is how to use the upload key exclusively (without the keystore file) to sign an app bundle for upload.

Comment: You need to use the keystore you made to hold your upload key when you created that - when you say that you have the upload key, what you hopefully mean (or at least need to mean) is that you have the keystore, and know the key alias and any password.  The play store will then accept the apk you sign this way (if it is the authorized key) and re-sign it with the distribution key which they hold on your behalf.  If you lost your keystore, then this new method has an ability to do an upload key reset, which the old method of signing the distribution apk yourself did not.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the process of signing your APK to upload to the play store hasn't really changed from the old days; the difference is that your signature only validates you to the play store, and then they replace it with a different one that validates the app to devices having older versions or other apks of yours with which it should share a security context.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks, please see my comment on the answer below (as to what is confusing me).

Answer (score 1):

A keystore is a container of private keys. The upload key is *in* the keystore (and so was your app signing key). You thus need the keystore containing the upload key to sign your app.

Edit: you'll find some more detailed description about the different types of elements at play here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB

Comment: Thanks, I am not understanding how this could be true. I have stored my keystore file <keystore>.jks - I also selected "Export upload key" and got a <private_key>.pepk. Two separate files. Also, when I generate the bundle, I need to enter two separate passwords. Once for the keystore file and one for the upload key. I guess I am just missing something, they seem to be two separate pieces of data, encrypted by two separate passwords...

Comment: Use the keystore and *not* the exported key.  There was no need to export it, and it's not even clear where you would be suppling and exported private key in the screenshot you posted - it is looking for a keystore, and the *name* of a key within.

Comment: The exported key is required when you enroll an existing app (i.e. already published) in App Signing by Play in the Play Console (not necessary for new apps) so you can securely transfer your key to Google. That .pepk file is not used for any other purposes. Regarding the 2 passwords, that's because the whole keystore is protected by a password and each key in the keystore (you can have multiple ones in a keystore) is as well protected by a password (people often use the same by convenience, but it doesn't have to be).